# Do the same results of a discrete metric space apply to a metric space $d(x,y)$ = $1/L$, $x\neq y$, $0$, $x=y$

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

What if a metric is the same as a discrete metric, but instead of being $1$ when $x\neq y$, it equals some real number $1/M$ instead?

For example would the metric space $(\mathbb{R},d)$ where $d$ is the discrete metric, but instead of $1$ is a real number $1/M$, be compact if and only if $\mathbb{R}$ is finite?

Comment: Compactness is a topological property, it depends only on the topology, not on the metric inducing it.

Answer (score 0):

If, on a set $X$ you define $d_K(x,y)=K$, for some $K\in(0,\infty)$, then you get a metric (which is the discrete one if $K=1$), and, for any value of $K$, the topology induced by that metric is the discrete one, that is, it's the topology for which *every* subset of $X$ is open. So, yes, $X$ endowed with such a metric is compact if and only if $X$ is finite.